# Всегда ли выполняется выполняется блок finally?

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch

Брюс Эккель в "Философия Java" пишет на стр. 388 что

> блок finally выполняется всегда

но на на стр. 400 прямо противоположное утверждение, что он может и не выполнятся

> в случае неудачи при конструировании блок finally не выполняется

контекст из книги для второго утверждения с примером кода:

```
//: exceptions/Cleanup.java
// Гарантированное освобождение ресурса
public class Cleanup {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     lnputFile in = new InputFile("Cleanup.java")j
     try {
       String s;
       int i = 1;
       while((s = in.getLine()) != null)
             ; // Обработка данных по строкам...
  } catch(Exception e) {
     System.0ut.println("Перехвачено исключение Exception в main");
     e .printStackTrace(System.out);
  } finally {
     in.dispose();
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Ошибка при конструировании InputFile");
}
}
} /* Output:
dispose() успешен
*///:~
```

> Присмотритесь повнимательнее к логике происходящего: объект lnputFile фактически
> конструируется в собственном блоке try. Если при конструировании произойдет ошиб­
> ка, программа входит во внешний блок catch, а метод dispose() не вызывается. Но если
> конструирование проходит успешно, необходимо проследить за тем, чтобы с объектом
> были выполнены завершающие действия, поэтому сразу же после конструирования
> создается новый блок try. Блок finally, выполняющий завершающие действия, свя­зан с внутренним блоком try; **в случае неудачи при конструировании блок finally не выполняется**, но он всегда будет выполнен в случае успешного конструирования

Comment: `finally` всегда выполняется если вы зашли в соответствующий `try`. В данном примере исключение до `try` приводит к тому что весь `try`, включая `finally` пропускается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> в случае неудачи при конструировании блок finally не выполняется

Имеется в виду неудача (`Exception`) при конструировании на этой строчке:

```
InputFile in = new InputFile("Cleanup.java");
```

При возникновении исключения внутри конструктора `InputFile` выполнение прерывается и пeреходит во внешний `catch`, а во внутренний `try` не заходит и в `finally` не попадает.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Меня просто смутило словосочетание "блок finally", ему следовало бы лучше написать " внутренний блок try ... catch ... finally не выполняется", а то получается блок finally как бы отдельно от общей конструкции рассматривается.

Ну а вообще если выполнить System.exit() в try или catch то finally не выполнится, так что всё равно его первое утверждение неверно.